# Keypress event for textarea for backspace

Tags: php, jquery, events, textarea, keypress

In my project, I am showing the remaining character length for a textarea for adding reviews, in a span while user types on the textarea.

The following is the keypress event :

```
$('#reviewtxt').keypress(function(){

            if($('#reviewtxt').val().length > 1000){
                return false;
            }
            if($.trim($('#reviewtxt').val()) != "")
            {
                $("#reviewremaining").html("Remaining Characters : " +(1000 - $('#reviewtxt').val().length));
            }
        });
```

HTML Code for the textarea

```
$data = array(
        'name'        => 'reviewtxt',
        'id'          => 'reviewtxt',
        'value'       => '',
        'rows'        => '10',
        'cols'        => '50',
        'style'       => 'border-radius:3px;border:1px solid rgba(75,156,255,1);margin-top:10px;',
        'placeholder'   => lang('type_here').' (Press Enter key to send your review) ',
        'onkeypress'    => 'submitreview(\''.base_url().'\',\''.$pgmresult->id.'\',\''.$id.'\',event,\'0\')'
        );
        echo form_textarea($data);?>
        <span id='reviewremaining' style="color:red;font-size: 13px;"></span>
```

AJAX :

```
function submitreview(baseurl,videoid,userid,e,type)
{ 
    $("#reviewremaining").show();
    $("#reviewremaining").html('');
    var reviewtxt=$.trim($("#reviewtxt").val());
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13)
    {
        if(reviewtxt=="")
        { 
            $("#reviewremaining").html('Please enter your review');
            $("#reviewtxt").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        { 
            if(reviewtxt.length>1000)
            {
                $("#reviewremaining").html('Review cannot exceed more than 1000 characters');
                $("#reviewtxt").focus();
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                dataType:"text",
           data:"reviewtxt="+reviewtxt+"&videoid="+videoid+"&userid="+userid+"&type="+type,
                url:baseurl+"video/submitreview",
                success:function(response)
                { 

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that, I am able to press another key even if the length exceeds the maximum. Suppose the maximum length is 500 characters then, the function will `return false` only when I press 501th character so that I need to delete that character in order to save the review. Also I want to show the remaining characters when I click on backspace or delete button.

Currently if I type 300 characters, then it will show Remaining characters : 300, then if I copy-paste some other lines, the text in span will still remain as same.

How to fix this problem? Can anyone help e to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also use maxlength="500"? for check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `keyup` event and call same function mouseup too

[**Here is fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mn8mF/)

```
$('#reviewtxt').keyup(function()
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mn8mF/1/)

Comment: @Neophyte..Thanks it is what I expected.

Comment: welcome.if you update remaining chars while pressing backspace mean you call the same function in keydown Event too..

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the problem change from `if($('#reviewtxt').val().length > 1000)` to `if($('#reviewtxt').val().length >= 1000)`. As you can see you need to include the last character for it to return false. Otherwise it will only return false on the (limit+1)th character.